# Swift- passing data from a multiple-section tableview to ViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I have a two-section tableview (see image below)

[image]

When I click row "A", another tableview shows up with letter "A"

[image]

When I click row "B", another tableview shows up with letter "B"

[image]

How can I pass the letter "C" to another tableview when I click row C ?

Here's my code in TableView:
import UIKit

class manhinh1: UITableViewController {

```
var UserDefault:NSUserDefaults!
var array:[[String]]!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    UserDefault = NSUserDefaults()
    array = [["A","B"],["C","D","E"]]

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return array.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    if section == 0 {
    return array[0].count
    }
    if section == 1 {
    return array[1].count
    }
    return 1
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    if indexPath.section == 0 {
    cell.textLabel?.text = array[0][indexPath.row]
    }
    if indexPath.section == 1 {
    cell.textLabel?.text = array[1][indexPath.row]
    }
    // Configure the cell...

    return cell
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    var row = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!.row

    UserDefault.setObject(array[0][row], forKey: "selected")
}
```

}

Here's the code in second view:
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
var UserDefault:NSUserDefaults!
@IBOutlet weak var lbldata: UILabel!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    UserDefault = NSUserDefaults()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a     }
    lbldata.text = UserDefault.objectForKey("selected") as! String
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

I did try a few code in prepareForSegue, but it didn't work. I hope you guys can show me a way. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have to get the row and the section to access your multidimensional array. Then get the destination view controller of your segue and assign the corresponding value from the array to the UserDefault property:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    var row = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!.row
    var section = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!.section

    var destinationViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewController 

    destinationViewController.UserDefault.setObject(array[section][row], forKey: "selected")
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I have been looking for. I kept looking for something like DidSelectSection but swift doesn't have that. Thanks Daniel. Btw, I did vote for your answer, but it said "Once you earn a total of 15 reputation, your votes will change the publicly displayed post score". Is voting the way to say thanks in stackoverflow ? I'm new here.

Comment: No problem Tuan, upvoting and marking the answer as correct helps others to separate relevant answers from those that aren't. If you post a correct answer and it is marked so you earn reputation which will give you more rights like for example commenting on answers and so on.